# Copying worksheet from a source file to the active workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have wrote the following code.

```
Sub copysheet()
Dim source_wb As Workbook
Set source_wb = Workbooks.Open("H:\Q1Data.xlsx")

source_wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy  Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

I think the problem is in copy-paste line. I found other codes but I don't want to complicate my code for such a simple purpose. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can also try using `ThisWorkbook` in place of `ActiveWorkbook`. When you open the file, you transfer the focus to that workbook and thus became the `ActiveWorkbook`. Using `ThisWorkbook` allows you to work on the workbook that contains the code rather than the currently active one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, you can also try below. HTH.

```
source_wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the ActiveWorkbook as a variable and reference it during the copy sheet process

```
Dim current_wb as Workbook
Dim source_wb As Workbook

Set current_wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set source_wb = Workbooks.Open("H:\Q1Data.xlsx")

source_wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Copy Before:=current_wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

current_wb.Save
current_wb.Close
```